# VBA Excel Merging of Cells based on a Specific cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to automate the merging of cells based by column for multiple columns based on the information in a specific column.

Based on the below picture the values in column c will determine the number of rows that need to be merged together for Columns A through K. With each change in the value in Column C - the merging would begin again.

[image]

```
Private Sub MergeCells_C() 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
    Dim rngMerge As Range, cell As Range 
    Set rngMerge = Range("C1:C1000") 'Set the range limits here 

MergeAgain: 

    For Each cell In rngMerge 
        If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then 
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge 
            GoTo MergeAgain 
        End If 
    Next 

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  See also [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried the below which works fine on Column C, but I don't know how to make the other columns I need to merge to use Column C as the guide for merging the other columns.

Comment: Private Sub MergeCells_C()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim rngMerge As Range, cell As Range
    Set rngMerge = Range("C1:C1000") 'Set the range limits here

MergeAgain:
    For Each cell In rngMerge
        If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
            GoTo MergeAgain
        End If
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Comment: Please don't expect anyone to read code in comments.  Revise your question and include the additional information, there, where it is most visible (and can also be properly formatted for legibility)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Sub MergeCellsByC()

    Dim c As Range, sht As Worksheet, currV
    Dim n As Long, rw As Range, r As Range

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Set c = sht.Range("C4") 'adjust to suit....
    currV = Chr(0)          'start with a dummy value

    Do
        If c.Value <> currV Then
            If n > 1 Then
                Set rw = c.EntireRow.Range("A1:K1") 'A1:K1 relative to the row we're on...
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                'loop across the row and merge the cells above
                For Each r In rw.Cells
                    r.Offset(-n).Resize(n).Merge
                Next r
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
            currV = c.Value
            n = 1
        Else
            n = n + 1 'increment count for this value
        End If

        If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then Exit Do 'exit on first empty cell
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0) 'next row down
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim - almost there but it isn't detecting the change in the column c value; right now the above code is doing one big merge for each column; I need it to merge the rows where the value in column C are the same

Comment: It worked for me, so there maybe something specific to your dataset which I'm missing.  Can you share the worksheet (or a mocked-up equivalent?)

Comment: how do I attach a sample file

Comment: You can upload it to a file sharing site and provide a URL (e.g. box, dropbox, google drive, etc)